# How to set a default value for a checkbox

Tags: html, angular, typescript

How do I set this angular checkbox to have a default Checked value.  Please I just want a simple answer.

```
  <p class="card-text">Please indicate which public organizations have been notified.</p>
          <div for="stakeholders" class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" checked name="stakeholders" [(ngModel)]="statusBoard.stakeholders">
            <label for="stakeholders">Are any stakeholders involved?</label>
          </div>
```

Comment: [checked]="statusBoard.stakeholders?.length"

Comment: <input type="checkbox" checked name="stakeholders" [(ngModel)]="statusBoard.stakeholders" checked="true">

Comment: Sorry folks. None of these solutions work.  Very frustrated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your component.ts, set `true` on `statusBoard.stakeholders`.

```js
this.statusBoard.stakeholders = true;
```

Comment: This did it.  I can't thank you folks enough.  This forum is so helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Use checked like below

```
  <p class="card-text">Please indicate which public organizations have been 
  notified. 
  </p>
      <div for="stakeholders" class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" checked name="stakeholders" 
            [(ngModel)]="statusBoard.stakeholders" 
            [checked]="statusBoard.stakeholders">
        <label for="stakeholders">Are any stakeholders involved?</label>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The ng-checked directive sets the checked attribute of a checkbox or a radiobutton.
try this..

```
<input type="checkbox" name="stakeholders" [(ngModel)]="statusBoard.stakeholders" ng-checked="true">
```

instead of this..

```
<input type="checkbox" checked name="stakeholders" [(ngModel)]="statusBoard.stakeholders">
```

Answer (score 0):

remove checked and ng-checked, just change the value of statusBoard.stakeholders

```
   <input type="checkbox" name="stakeholders" 
     [(ngModel)]="statusBoard.stakeholders" >

 //in your .ts
 this.statusBoard.stakeholders=true.
```

Well, you can also use [ngModel] and (ngModelChange) in the way

```
<input type="checkbox" name="stakeholders" 
     [ngModel]="!statusBoard.stakeholders" 
     (ngModelChange)="statusBoard.stakeholders=!$event" 
>
```

So if checked, the value of statusBoard.stakeholders is false and if is unchecked the value of statusBoard.stakeholders is true, but I don't know if this is what you are looking for